# make sure ajax output is up to date

Tags: jquery, post

I have an Ajax jquery function ($.post) that retrieves json data.  One of the ways it gets executed is by keydown ($('#lkj').keyup(function(event)) with a 250 ms delay. One problem however is that the data retrieved is not always up to date. Especially when the user has a high ping towards the server. When i for example type "test", the jquery .post script will get (depending on my typing speed) executed between two to four times:

1. t
2. te
3. tes
4. test

Sometimes the instance containing "te" is slow and is last the complete and therefore overwrites the output written by the instance containing "test". How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique is using a sequence number with your request, and processing the output only if it matches the latest request sequence number.

For example:

```
var reqSeq = 0;
```

When making your $.post call:

```
reqSeq++;
$.post('yourserver.com/yoururl?data=X&seq='+reqSeq, function(data) {

    // convert from JSON etc..

    // check if this response is for the latest request, if not, ignore response.
    if(data.seqNum < reqSeq) return;

    // process the response

});
```

Comment: Isn't that the same then as using async:false?

Comment: @Michael - No. Unlike `async:false`, the above method still allows multiple asynchronous requests without blocking the calling thread. Just that, only the response for the latest request will be taken into consideration. `async:false` will block the calling thread till the response is received.

Comment: hmmmm I see what you mean... I think that will do it, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You need to throttle the event, not just have a delay.

What is happening right now: You type "test" quickly. 4 keyup events fire back to back, and 250ms later you get 4 ajax requests, one for each event.

What you want to happen: You type "test" quickly. If another keyup event is received inside of 250ms after the first keyup event, then you want to cancel the first event and reset the timer, do this again each time you get a keyup inside of 250ms. This would end up being just 1 ajax request.

You can implement that manually, or there are plugins that can handle it, this one:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: @chcherry I think I already have that:


`$('#lkj').keyup(function(event) {
    if( $(this).timeout ) clearTimeout( $(this).timeout );
    $(this).timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       DoAjax();
    },250);

});`

Comment: If you are getting all 4 of those requests as you say, then that code isn't working as you expect. You can try using `$(this).data('timeout')` to store and retrieve the setTimeout handle.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can add in your response message "text" that was used in making result. And check this text(that plays role - flag) on compatibility with current date, in case current value was changed you should not put your result int field.

I think that would be nice if you set flag that means if executed ajax request now or not. This help avoid situation when user makes fast change of text and server get a lot of uptodate requests.